# REST Sum SharePoint Values without else if

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, rest, sharepoint

Is there a more efficient way to sum a series of results that get pulled from SharePoint REST? I have a list with 300+ records with a column with values in it and I'm trying to display the summed results broken up by their SupportValue (X & Y). It works with an else if but I have many more SupportValues. Is there a better or more efficient method for this?

```
function fnFunction(total) {
var AFSum,EAPSum,EURSum,NEASCASum;
$.getJSON("../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListName?$select=SupportValue,AuthorizedNumber", function (data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, i) {
        var AFCount,EAPCount,EURCount,NEASCACount = {};
        if (AFSum == null && i.SupportValue == 'A') {
            AFCount = {EstCount: parseInt(item.AuthorizedNumber)};
            AFSum = AFCount; 
        } else if (i.SupportValue == 'A') {
            AFSum.EstCount += parseInt(item.AuthorizedNumber);
        } else if (EAPSum == null && i.SupportValue == 'B') {
            EAPCount = {EstCount: parseInt(item.AuthorizedNumber)};
            EAPSum = EAPCount; 
        } else if (i.SupportValue == 'B') {
            EAPSum.EstCount += parseInt(item.AuthorizedNumber);
        } else if (EURCount == null && i.SupportValue == 'C') {
            EURCount = {EstCount: parseInt(item.AuthorizedNumbers)};
            EURSum = EURCount; 
        } else if (i.SupportValue == 'C') {
            EURSum.EstCount += parseInt(item.AuthorizedLGF);
        } else if (NEASCASum == null && i.SupportValue == 'D') {
            NEASCACount = {EstCount: parseInt(item.AuthorizedNumbers)};
            NEASCASum = NEASCACount; 
        } else if (i.SupportValue == 'D') {
            NEASCASum.EstCount += parseInt(item.AuthorizedNumbers);
        }
    });
    var percentAF = Math.round((parseInt(AFSum.EstCount) / parseInt(total)) * 100);
    $("#AF-SUM").html(<div class='progress md-progress'><div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' style='width: "+percentAF+"%;' aria-valuenow='"+percentAF+"' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'>"+AFSum.EstCount+"</div></div>);
    $("#EAP-SUM").html(EAPSum.EstCount);
})
}
```

Comment: Do you also have lots of `<letters>Sum` and `<letters>Count` variables, for each `SupportValue`?

Comment: No just the two used in the above.  The data is pulled from SharePoint REST and each record has 1 SupportValue and 1 AuthorizedNumber. To capture all the SupportValues I have to create a new variable for each one. The current product has 24 variables (12 ea).

Comment: Can you post a couple more examples of the repetitive code? If it's not the sum/count ones that are being repeated, I'm not immediately seeing the pattern

Comment: I added two more categories to show how long it can get and there are 12 categories. I only put in 2 originally now it has 4.

Comment: Thanks, though it looks like you *do* actually have lots of `<letters>Sum` and `<letters>Count` variables, for each `SupportValue`, as I was thinking initially :)

Comment: Try to use something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/aggregations-element-list. I don't know - may be you can call SharePoint with CAML Query and its Aggregations element. https://codeatwork.wordpress.com/2017/10/13/aggregation-using-caml-query/   What SharePoint version are you use ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have access to the data source via their REST service.

Comment: What version of SharePoint ? You can use caml query in REST calls. But this element (Aggregations) can be in REST higher 2010

Comment: Good ole 2010. I have a javascript application built over the REST service. Is there a better way to do the above? It seems really inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using an object to map the `SupportValue`s to indicators, like `B` to `EAP`. Then, you can `reduce` the `data.d.results` array into an object, whose keys are the indicators, and values are the sum count for that indicator. After that, you can iterate over the object's `entries`, calculate the percentage, create the appropriate HTML string, and use the indicator to select the appropriate element in the DOM and set its HTML to that HTML string; something like the following:

```
function fnFunction(total) {
  // is total really not a number when it gets passed?
  total = parseInt(total);
  $.getJSON("../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListName?$select=SupportValue,AuthorizedNumber", function(data) {
    const indicatorBySupportValue = {
      A: 'AF',
      B: 'EAP',
      C: 'EUR',
      D: 'NEASCA'
    };
    const countByIndicator = data.d.results.reduce((a, { SupportValue, AuthorizedNumber }) => {
      const indicator = indicatorBySupportValue[SupportValue];
      a[indicator] = (a[indicator] || 0) +  parseInt(AuthorizedNumber);
      return a;
    }, {});
    /*
      now you have an object like:
      {
        AF: 5,
        EAP: 10,
        EUR: 12
      }
    */
    Object.entries(countByIndicator).forEach(([indicator, count]) => {
      const percent = Math.round(count / total);
      const html = "<div class='progress md-progress'><div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' style='width: " + percent + "%;' aria-valuenow='" + percent + "' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100'>" + count + "</div></div>";
      $('#' + indicator + '-SUM').html(html);
    });
  });
}
```

Just an idea, but you might consider using `Number(` instead of `parseInt(` if you're just trying to cast a non-number to a number.

Comment: This is perfect. Took me a bit to figure out and walk myself through it but thank you CertainPerformance. Dramatically less code and a little faster too.

Comment: Certain, I'm running into an issue with this script in IE11 - getting a SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' at the const countByIndicator line. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: IE does not support arrow functions, nor any other ES6+ syntax. Best solution would be to integrate Babel into your build process to transpile your code from ES6+ syntax to ES5 automatically: https://babeljs.io/repl/ (you'll need an `Object.entries` polyfill too)